# Wine, Steam, Games crash after launch.

Tags: wine, games, steam

I'm running Steam through Wine since most or possibly all my games aren't officially out on Linux, and every time I start a game either a few seconds later or my first key stroke or mouse click, the game crashes.

One of the reasons I went to Ubuntu was that everyone says I can run Steam and all of my Games through Wine. But if that is not going to be the case, I would have stuck with Vista.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but there is a great misconception that ALL Steam games are running on Linux. Steam is currently working hard to introduce Steam to Linux and it's already ported a lot of VALVE games to its native Linux Steam client. Steam offers mostly games produced by 3rd party companies and they cannot force them to make them work under Linux. There will ALWAYS be games that are not running on Linux, Windows or MAC... if you are patient enough, more and more games WILL run under Linux though. Always check WINEHQ to see which software is tested to run.

Comment: That being said, the more games will run under Linux, the more people will switch from Windows, and the more people who use Linux, the more reason companies will have to make stuff work with Linux too. It's a slow process, but we'll get there eventually.

Comment: I suggest you install the native Steam client in Linux and play whatever you can using Linux. For the games that give you trouble, dual-boot and play those in Windows. However, don't keep using Windows for everything, even if it's only from a security perspective ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the Linux version of Steam.

http://media.steampowered.com/client/installer/steam.deb 
you can download from the url 
http://store.steampowered.com/about/

One tip... pay attention to new games that steam are porting to linux, you can fallow on this url

http://store.steampowered.com/browse/linux/